# Server-side Configuration for cross-origin requests

Tags: apache, api, rest, virtualhost

I have a development server currently serving (Apache) an API that is accessible from across domains and following is my VirtualHost configuration for it:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

I'm not fully aware of what the above settings do and now that I have to move this to production, I'm not sure if this configuration is production-ready. Can you help shed some light on the implications if I were to move this to production as-is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These configuration options allow your application to run as an API. They are a neccessary part of [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

The first four lines are setting headers that can be used to control how your API is accessed and the remaining lines allow for `OPTIONS` requests which will check if the request is allowed or not. More info here - [universal-CORS-htaccess](http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2013/10/03/universal-CORS-htaccess/).

`Access-Control` headers are set to allow requests for resources from a different domains. They also allow you to restrict what domains access your API resources and what methods are used. For example your API might be used to exclusively serve resources to a certain domain using a `POST` request. You could therefore use:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://foo.example"
Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST"
```

These configurations are necessary for your application to run as an API but as to how production ready it is? Without having more details about your server environment and application framework etc it is hard to say. You may want to move these options out of a `.htaccess` file or enable your `.htaccess` file in the first place. But you do need them.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have set these options in my VirtualHost configuration for the domain that is serving the API. The link you provided explains this to much greater detail. My application is a native Python+CGI code served by Apache. What other details do you need from me to ensure these options are production-ready? I'm only concerned if these settings expose any loop holes that can be potentially exploited.

Comment: No worries. I think you are "production-ready" right now. The only precautions I might take are the ones I've mentioned already i.e. remove the `*` wildcard from the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` replacing it with the domain you know will be using the API (if there is one) and similarly restricting the allowed Methods to those you know will be used.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have accepted your answer, but will have to wait 14 hours before I can grant you the bounty.